# Building+linking libpng in Android Studio with CMake on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

I'm trying to start a native app project with Android Studio and CMake on Windows 10, but I'm stuck at including libpng.

For starters it's the first time I've seen a CMakeLists.txt file. It took me a day to figure out `target_link_libraries(native-activity ... png)` could not be `target_link_libraries(png native-activity ...)` since all the error messages were about files not being created and commands failing due to missing requirements from the toolchain (why were the essential errors at the end of the list? not cool!).

After finally managing to include libpng in the project I now get a build error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
...
error: unknown target CPU 'armv5te'
CMake Error at scripts/genout.cmake:78 (message):
    Failed to generate
    C:/APP_PATH/app/libpng-1.6.28/build/scripts/symbols.out.tf1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've recursively grep'ed my project, .android, .AndroidStudio2.2 directories, as well as filenames, and found absolutely nothing with armv5te except for the genout.cmake. My abiFilters line is `abiFilters 'x86'`.

How do I build libpng to link to my native app? Also, in Android Studio it shows the project now includes the libpng source files (with no less than 9 projects dedicated to it!). Is there any way to remove it?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# build native_app_glue as a static lib
add_library(app-glue STATIC ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

set(png_src_dir ../../../../libpng-1.6.28)
set(PNG_STATIC ON)
add_subdirectory(${png_src_dir} ${png_src_dir}/build)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++14")

add_library(native-activity SHARED
            main.cpp logger.cpp logger.h game.cpp game.h
            shaders.cpp shaders.h assets.cpp assets.h)

target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue
                           C:/devlibs/include
                           ${png_src_dir})

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(native-activity app-glue android log EGL GLESv2 png)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed libpng to work with android NDK app (CMake build system instead of Android.mk) as static library. I used [libpng-android repackaging](https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android). Here are things I've done:

1. `git clone https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android.git` into `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}` (I used `${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_DIRECTORY}/sources/android`).
2. Add `${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_DIRECTORY}` (`home/username/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` for me) to global `$PATH` variable which is needed for build script).
3. Build lib with `ndk-build` (there is `./build.sh` for that in directory with lib). Library will be built for different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) targets ( `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi`, `x86_64` etc).
4. At this point you have library headers at `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/jni` and `libpng.a` at `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/obj/local/${ANDROID_ABI}/`, where `${ANDROID_ABI}` is target platform.
5. Finally you could include lib at `CMakeLists.txt`. `libpng` requires [zlib compression library](http://www.zlib.net) so you need to link against it aswell (`zlib` is provided by android studio so just add `-lz` flag).

Here is related piece from my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(libpng STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpng PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/obj/local/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpng.a)

add_library(appManager SHARED src/main/cpp/appManager.cpp)

target_include_directories(appManager PRIVATE ${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/jni/)

target_link_libraries(appManager
                       android
                       libpng
                       z)
```

Few things to note there:

- `${ANDROID_ABI}` is a variable set by Android Studio build system.
- Once again: you need to link against [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html), that is why we have `libpng z` instead of `libpng` in `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: I'm on windows, I can't use build.sh, and this repackaging is flaky (namely bug #130 where they just disabled arm instead of actually fixing it) I might as well include the dozen files in my project and avoid the linking altogether.

Comment: @Olivetree there is one command in `build.sh`: `ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./ $@`, that could be executable manually without .sh. Considering "bug 130" - agree, looks weird.

Comment: true, but the last point remains: I might as well add the files manually to my project and avoid the burden of managing this build and its toolchain setup altogether. But I don't really trust that method: have you seen the official libpng build procedure? It's a bit too complex to expect to do that without issues.

Answer (score 5):

With Android Studio 3.6, including libpng into your project is rather easy.

- Download the latest sources from [sourceforge](https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.37/lpng1637.zip) and unpack the zip file.
- In Android Studio, make sure you have **NDK** and **CMake** installed (in ***SDK Manager***)
- Create a new *Android Library* module, call it **pngAndroid** (I would recommend
  to set the **Package Name** to `org.libpng.libpng`, same as MacOS). Keep it Java, and choose the min SDK that fits your app.
- For this module, choose ***File/Link C++ Project with Gradle***. Find **CMakleLists.txt** of **libpng** that you downloaded as step 1.
- In the **pngAndroid**'s `build.gradle`, add

  ```
  android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.targets "png_static"
  ```
- In ***Project Structure*** dialog, specify module dependency between your Module and **pngAndroid**.

When you build the **pngAndroid** Module, you will see files **libpng16d.a** in **build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj** directory under **pngAndroid**.

In your Module, you also have **CMakleLists.txt**. In this script, you have a target, *e.g.*

```
add_library(native-library SHARED …
```

You should add **libpng** as dependency of **native-library**:

```
target_link_libraries(native-library libpng)
```

Elsewhere in this **CMakleLists.txt** you should define the imported **libpng**:

```
add_library(libpng STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpng PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ../pngAndroid/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpng16d.a)
set_target_properties(libpng PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    ../../lpng1637)
set_target_properties(libpng PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES
    z)
```

Note that here I used relative paths *a)* to the **pngAndroid** Module that you added to your Android Studio project, and *b)* to the **libpng** sources that you downloaded. In your setup, the relative paths may be different.

---

For completeness, here is a cleaned-up `build.gradle` script for **pngAndroid** to build shared library **libpng16d.so**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DSKIP_INSTALL_ALL=YES"
                targets "png"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('../../lpng1637/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

When you build the module, you get in **build/outputs** an **aar** file that contains the **jni** directory with **`armeabi-v7a/libpng16d.so`** and all other ABI variants.

---

Last, it's worth mentioning that Google [is working on an easier native package manager](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/916). Unfortunately, it's still not released.

Comment: Could you please clarify some moments for me, this way that you provided we create a module and (like) including `libpng` into this module. Result is - we have module with `libpng`, but I still don't understand how I can include this module to my cpp project? I mean when I try to add header `#include <png.h>` in my cpp files I am getting error  `png.h file not found`... What am I doing wrong? I think I need to add some configuration to project ` CMakeList.txt`, right?

Comment: The code above builds **libpng** for Android. If you want to use it as one of C++ dependencies, it's much easier to use the STATIC version. I have expanded my answer to explain how this dependency can be defined.

Comment: What do you mean here - `In Project Structure dialog, specify module dependency between your Module and pngAndroid`? I opened Project Stucture dialog, but I don't understand how I need to specify dependency between myModule(I think you mean app module) and pngAndroid (it is actually also module)... ?

Comment: I would like to ask about STATIC ver of lib. As far as I understand it is means that for example I have compile source files and added them as static lib, so if I need to update my lib (someone push new commit) I need to recompile source files again and add substitute lib with new one, right? I mean with static version of lib it is going to be a bit harder if you need to update your lib... No?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko the difference between static and shared is minor. At any rate, Play Store requires that all binaries be packaged in the APK (or AAB). So, in both cases you must deploy a new version. In both cases, you must compile the library (e.g. **libpng**). For static, this will also cause CMake to link again the binaries that depend on **libpng** (e.g. **libnative-activity.so**). Note that if you go for shared **libpng**, you also must make sure that it is packaged into the APK.