# How to build libpng NDK CMake android?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, libpng

There is libpng http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

I need to include it to my android project. I found the way how to make it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42456604/5709159

1. `git clone https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android.git` into `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}` (I used `${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_DIRECTORY}/sources/android`).
2. Add `${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT_DIRECTORY}` (`home/username/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle` for me) to global `$PATH` variable which is needed for build script).
3. Build lib with `ndk-build` (there is `./build.sh` for that in directory with lib). Library will be built for different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) targets ( `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi`, `x86_64` etc).
4. At this point you have library headers at `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/jni` and `libpng.a` at `${YOUR_LIBS_FOLDER}/libpng-android/obj/local/${ANDROID_ABI}/`, where `${ANDROID_ABI}` is target platform.
5. Finally you could include lib at `CMakeLists.txt`. `libpng` requires [zlib compression library](http://www.zlib.net) so you need to link against it aswell (`zlib` is provided by android studio so just add `-lz` flag).

Problem is at case 2. I cloned the lib under ndk root dir/sources/android, but then author say that I need to add andoroid ndk dir to global path? What does it mean?

If I miss this case and try to make case 3, I opened the lib, found the `build.sh` file, double click it and nothing happen... As far as I understand `.sh` files not executable for Windows, so ...

What am I doing wrong? What does case 2 mean?

Comment: The poster of that answer provided a solution that works on Linux. The author of that post also offers a work-around for the `.sh` file in the comments below the answer. Did you try this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582935/192373